# How do I use Elastic MapReduce to run an XSLT transformation on millions of small S3 xml files?

Tags: xml, amazon-s3, hadoop, mapreduce, xslt

More specifically, is there a somewhat easy streaming solution?

Answer (score 2):

See this link:  [How do I process files, one per map?](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/streaming.html#How+do+I+process+files%2C+one+per+map%3F)

- Upload your data to an S3 bucket
- Generate a file containing the full s3n:// path to each file
- Write a mapper script that:

  - Pulls 'mapred_work_output_dir' out of the environment (*)
  - Performs XSLT transform based on the name of the file, saving to the output directory
- Write an identity reducer that does nothing
- Upload your mapper / reducer scripts to an S3 bucket
- Test your script via the AWS EMR console

(*) Streaming puts your jobconf in the processes environment. See code [here](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hadoop/mapreduce/trunk/src/contrib/streaming/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/streaming/PipeMapRed.java?view=markup).